# Unexpected token (*)

Tags: javascript, npm, import

This line of code is giving me problems,

```
import * as posenet from '@tensorflow-models/posenet'
```

And I get this error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *',

I am using the latest version of chrome and have npm package '@tensorflow-models/posenet' installed.I am using npm package 'http-server' to localhost my page.

Comment: you might need babel to transpile ?

Comment: if  this js file is being compiled by the browser you need type="module" in script tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't import npm packages directly like that as the browser has no idea where a package on your server is stored.

In the browser you import javascript files directly using it's path, ie `from 'some/file.js'`. Also your code has to be in a module type script element for it to use the import/export syntax. For instance

```
<script type="module">
  import * as someName from 'some/file.js';
</script>
```

Comment: It's a node module so which specific file do I import?

Answer (score 0):

When using TS in node, specify a correct `module` in `tsconfig.json`.

E.g,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
  }
}
```